# Struts 2 - Parameters passed to the action through Hyperlink are coming as null in the action

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have been struggling with this question since a week and thought to finally put it here. I working on an Struts 2 application and trying to call a new action from jsp file with some parameters, but the parameters are coming as null in the action.

In the below jsp file, i am creating a new hyperlink entry called pdfName and then appending them in a table called pdfList. When a user clicks on a button called ListPDF. All these links are displayed successfully. However, I want that when a user clicks on the URL, a request is sent to action which provides back a byte[] of pdf data which is then streamed on browser.

**JSP:**

```
<s:url var="docs" action="fetchDocument">
    <s:param name="doc_name" value="%{docItem.name}"></s:param>
    <s:param name="doc_id" value="%{docItem.objectId}"> </s:param>
</s:url>        

var pdfName = '<a href=' +"${docs}" +' target="_blank">' + docItem.name + '</a>';

$('#pdfList').append('<tr><td>' + checkBox + '</td><td>' + pdfName + '</td></tr>');
```

The problem is that the parameters doc_name and doc_id are coming as null in the action.

**Action:**

```
package com.b2bbank.mos.web.action;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;

public class FetchDocument extends Base {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String doc_name;
private String doc_id;
public InputStream streamforPDFDoc;

public String fetchPDF() {

    HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
    System.out.println("Doc ID: " + doc_id);
    System.out.println("Document Name: " + doc_name);

    byte[] doc_data = WorkDeskIntegration.getDocument(doc_name, doc_id);
    response.setContentLength(doc_data.length);

    if (doc_data != null) {
        streamforPDFDoc = new ByteArrayInputStream(doc_data);
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}

public String getDoc_name() {
    return doc_name;
}

public void setDoc_name(String doc_name) {
    this.doc_name = doc_name;
}

public String getDoc_id() {
    return doc_id;
}

public void setDoc_id(String doc_id) {
    this.doc_id = doc_id;
}

public InputStream getStreamforPDFDoc() {
    return streamforPDFDoc;
}

public void setStreamforPDFDoc(InputStream streamforPDFDoc) {
    this.streamforPDFDoc = streamforPDFDoc;
}

}
```

**Struts.xml**

```
<action name="fetchDocument" class="com.b2bbank.mos.web.action.FetchDocument" method="fetchPDF">
        <result name="success" type="stream">
            <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param>
            <param name="inputName">streamforPDFDoc</param>
            <param name="bufferSize">8192</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

Can anybody help me in the correct direction? I have tried searching through countless posts on SO, but none of those worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Avoid using underscores for your fields, I would suggest to change doc_id to docId and regenerate getters and setters, change in jsp too. dothe same for doc_name -> docName

Comment: @GUISSOUMAIssam I changed the field names to without underscores as you suggested. But, I am still getting null values in action

Comment: if you add `console.log(pdfName)` what it prints in console, do you have url with params?

Comment: Please update your code with your latest changes so I can see if evrythings looks ok,